# How can I set \repeatTie to follow a note

Tags: lilypond

I need a small tie like the \repeatTie, but it has to be behind a note, not before:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\relative c' {
  \clef treble
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4

  r2 c4 d8 d~ 
  \repeat volta 2 {d8 e4. r2 r2 c4 d8 e~ e2 e4 f8 d8~ 
  d4 r4 e f8 f~ f g4. r2 r2 e4 f8 g~ g2 g4 a8 g~ g4
  r4 g a8 c~ c2. r8 c8~ c2. r4 c c c a8 g~ g4 r4 g a8 c~ 
  c2. r8 a~ a2. r4 g f f c8 d~ }
  \alternative {
    {d4 r4 c4 d8 d} 
    {d4\repeatTie  r r2 } 
  }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\laissezVibrer` should do the trick.  That's basically a half-tie to the right, like `\repeatTie` is a half-tie to the left.

Comment: This helped me, too. @MichaelSchmitz: Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted!